# How to get the URL of a Link in a UIWebView?

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView loading a dynamic page. This dynamic page always has a link with the following HTML tag

```
<a id=xyz href=url>X Y Z</a>
```

The url of this link is also dynamic. Also, this link might be in a different place in the hierarchy of the HTML code of said page. What I would like to do is get the url from this link & store it in something like an NSString or something similar for use elsewhere.

Is there anyway to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('xyz').href"];
```

to get the url as a string.

Answer (score 3):

If webView will be a reference to your UIWebView instance, use the following code:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('xyz').href"];
```

the ID of your element must be unique, so you'll be sure to find the correct one.